# Get order collection by order id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, order-collection

I am trying to get order collection by order id in Magento 2.

Here is my code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->load($oid);

echo $custLastName= $orders->getCustomerLastname();
```

But its is giving fatal error:

```
 Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection::getCustomerLastname()
```

Comment: use ```$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid);```

Comment: This method does not return customer information. So I need collection of it that provides customer information as well

Comment: check my answer just remove getCollection

Comment: Do not use ObjectManager. You can follow this [get Order Details using Order id In Magento 2](https://www.magespark.com/blog/post/how-to-get-order-details-using-order-id-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just Remove `getCollection()` :-

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orders = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid);

echo $custLastName= $orders->getCustomerLastname();
```

Comment: hi @Rathod, can we get the last itemSku from the order? if the order is placed with one or more sku.

Comment: only last item sku ?

Comment: yes @Rathod, can we get it?

Comment: im not sure but try this $order->getAllItems()->getLastItem()

Comment: No, this will give the last order item, but not the last sku in the particular order

Comment: $order->getAllItems()->getLastItem()->getSku();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99082/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rk-rathod).

Comment: caught Error: Call to a member function getLastItem() on array

Comment: You get a last item in array

Answer (score 5):

**The Following code will easily get Customer details, Billing, Shipping and order totals**

```
  $orderId = 1222;
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
  $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository')->get($orderId);

  /*get customer details*/

  $custLastName= $orders->getCustomerLastname();
  $custFirsrName= $orders->getCustomerFirstname();
  $ipaddress=$order->getRemoteIp();
  $customer_email=$order->getCustomerEmail();
  $customerid=$order->getCustomerId();

  /* get Billing details */  
  $billingaddress=$order->getBillingAddress();
  $billingcity=$billingaddress->getCity();      
  $billingstreet=$billingaddress->getStreet();
  $billingpostcode=$billingaddress->getPostcode();
  $billingtelephone=$billingaddress->getTelephone();
  $billingstate_code=$billingaddress->getRegionCode();

  /* get shipping details */

  $shippingaddress=$order->getShippingAddress();        
  $shippingcity=$shippingaddress->getCity();
  $shippingstreet=$shippingaddress->getStreet();
  $shippingpostcode=$shippingaddress->getPostcode();      
  $shippingtelephone=$shippingaddress->getTelephone();
  $shippingstate_code=$shippingaddress->getRegionCode();

 /* get  total */

  $tax_amount=$order->getTaxAmount();
  $total=$order->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: I placed this code in a file in a directory called "testcode" at the same level as public_html. Please tell me what should be the path \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php                                                                 
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Orders;                                
class ReadOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action                 
{
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
 \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo
) {
   $this->orderRepo = $orderRepo;
   parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
   $entity_id = '12'; // its called increment id
   $order = $this->orderRepo->get($entity_id);
   echo $order->getCustomerId();
   echo $order->getCustomerFirstname();
   echo $order->getCustomerEmail();

}
}
```

Don't use object manager anywhere and you can use the above code in block or helper anywhere to get the collection.

Hope this helps.